# Display picklist values in angular ng-options

Tags: visualforce, picklist, angular

I have a custom VisualForce page that has an angular controller running the page.  I have a `<select>` on the page and I'd like to populate the select via the `Describe` information from the picklist values on a custom field.  Is this even possible?  This would be in lieu of using an `<apex:selectList>` so that I can bind using angular.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "build it yourself" solution that I'm using in a project where the UI is all Angular. Would be happy to hear of a simpler approach if there is one ...

I have an `@RestResource` endpoint that returns a map keyed by first the SObject type then the field name with an array of these objects as the value:

```java
public class Option {
    public String label;
    public String value;
    public Option(String label, String value) {
        this.label = label;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

with the picklist values obtained from [DescribeFieldResult.getPicklistValues](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getPicklistValues).

I have an Angular service to get and cache this data so it can be added into the scope by the controllers.

Then in the Angular partials for the UI the picklist options are presented like this (*with `Claim__c` the SObjectType and `Reason__c` the SObjectField*):

```html
<select
        id="reason"
        name="reason"
        class="form-control inline"
        ng-options="o.value as o.label for o in picklists.Claim__c.Reason__c"
        ng-model="reason"/>
```

A gotcha is that if you are using record types there is no convenient API to get the appropriate picklist subset. [Picklist values by record type for AngularJS UI](https://force201.wordpress.com/2015/06/01/picklist-values-by-record-type-for-angularjs-ui/) describes a work-around for that.